# Service Account authentication credentials for Google Drive not working

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I create credentials for google service account from json file as follow:

```
using var stream = new FileStream(credentialFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
var credentials = ServiceAccountCredential.FromServiceAccountData(stream);
```

The service account has Domain-wide Delegation with scopes:

- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive
- https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets

The result is then used to create a DriveService or a SheetsService object.

```
sheetService = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credentials
});
driveService = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credentials
});
```

I've been succesfully interacting with Google Sheets API. Writing and reading without any issue, it just works fine.

As soon as I try to interact with Google Drive API things don't work because of lack of authentication. This code is an example:

```
var fileListRequest = DriveService.Files.List();
fileListRequest.Q = $"'{gDriveFolderID}' in parents";
var fileList = await fileListRequest.ExecuteAsync();
```

I get exception:
"The service drive has thrown an exception. HttpStatusCode is Unauthorized. Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See [https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project"](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project%22)

If instead of authenticating with a service account I authenticate with an ID client OAuth 2.0, which requires me to accept in a browser page, it works.
The problem is that this authentication expires.

I Know I could use the refresh token. But it also will expire at some point, and service accounts exist exactly to avoid refreshing authentication when dealing with internal data.

Comment: When you create `DriveService` you are not specifying the OAuth scope for Google Drive access. Specifying scopes when setting up delegation declares which scopes can be requested. Your code is not impersonating a user, which is required to use delegation. Improve your post with more complete code. The code fragments are too short.

Comment: The code I've posted is the code I'm using, is not a short version of it.
The BaseClientService.Initializer class does not have a Scope property I could use to specify the OAuth scope for Google Drive access.
I do not know how to make my code impersonate a user.
Can you elaborate on how you would achieve what you have said by building on my code?

Comment: Thanks for your input. "When you create DriveService you are not specifying the OAuth scope for Google Drive access" was the right reason for the failure. Addressing it solved the issue. I replyied with code the correctly builds credentials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is not complete, you are neither scoping your credentials nor using user impersonation.

```cs
var credentials = GoogleCredential.FromFile(credentialFileName)
    .CreateScoped(
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive", 
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets")
     // This is the email of the user in the domain where
     // the service account has domain wide delegation,
     // that you want to manipulate Drive files/Sheets for.
    .CreateWithUser("user1@your-domain.com");

var sheetService = new SheetsService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credentials
});
var driveService = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credentials
});
```

I'm not certain why it was working for Sheets before though.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to John Hanley's comment I was able to find the solution.
I assumed setting scopes at Domain-wide Delegation level was the way to go. I was wrong.

As John Hanley wrote I was "not specifying the OAuth scope for Google Drive access".

The following code achieves the needed result:

```
using var stream = new FileStream(credentialFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
var credentials = ServiceAccountCredential.FromServiceAccountData(stream);
credentials.Scopes = new[]
{
    DriveService.Scope.Drive
};
```

The property `credentials.Scopes` can be set to include the scopes needed.

Now it works.
Thanks again to John Hanley.

Comment: Your code is not impersonating a user. That probably means the service account is not using Domain Wide Delegation and instead has been granted access to a Drive Share directly. See Amanda's answer for how to specify the user to impersonate.

Comment: We crossed answers. Just know that your answer here is still not impersonating a user.

Comment: That's right, the service account has shared access to the drive resources. Accepted Amanda Tarafa Mas answer as it's more complete.